# Infinite smooth scrollX for HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview

How would you implement endless smooth horizontal scroll from left to right (and vice versa)?

`HorizontalScrollView` contains only one `TextView` element with quite long text inside therefore I want to scroll that text instead of user.

I found `ObjectAnimator` to be only one to achieve smooth scrolling. Now the problem is to loop it properly. I found two close solutions although they don't work as expected:

1. Use `CycleInterpolator()`. Can't achieve smooth behaviour:

   `ObjectAnimator animRight = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hScrollVIew, "scrollX", hScrollVIew.getRight());
   animRight.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
   animRight.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(1f));
   animRight.setDuration(4000);
   animRight.setStartDelay(0);
   animRight.start();`
2. Create 2 animations (left and right) which would call one after another. This solution has weird delay effect after first animation.

   ```
   final ObjectAnimator animRight = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hScrollVIew, "scrollX", holder.hsvTitleHolder.getRight());
   animRight.setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION);

   final ObjectAnimator animLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hScrollVIew, "scrollX", 0);
   animLeft.setDuration(SCROLL_DURATION);

   animRight.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
       Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
           hScrollVIew.clearAnimation();
           animLeft.start();
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
   });

   animLeft.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
           hScrollVIew.clearAnimation();
           animRight.start();
       }

       @Override
       public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
   });

   animRight.start();
   ```

If anyone faced similar problem please share your experience.

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/4xXMPTnq)

Comment: @pskink woah! That works like a charm! Thank you so much. I've been fighting with it for days. You might want to post this code as answer so I could accept as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the code like this:

```
    final HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextSize(48);
    tv.setText("Our evil heaven for living is to yearn others agreeable.");
    hsv.addView(tv);
    setContentView(hsv);

    View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator animRight = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(hsv, "scrollX", 0, tv.getWidth() - hsv.getWidth());
            animRight.setRepeatCount(3);
            // you could use CycleInterpolator(0.5f) but the 
            // effect with CycleInterpolator is not so smooth
            // so use that custom Interpolator
            animRight.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
                @Override
                public float getInterpolation(float input) {
                    return (float) Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.PI * input), 2);
// you could also use similar interpolation:
//                    return (float) (1 - Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * input)) / 2;
                }
            });
            animRight.setDuration(4000);
            animRight.start();
        }
    };
    tv.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```